# Will older iPad Pro 11 (2018) folio cases fit the iPad Air 4 (2020)?

Tags: ipad

Apple’s folio case and keyboard folio case are stupidly expensive, but the old pro 11 (2018) cases are cheap on eBay. Will older iPad Pro 11 (2018) folio cases fit the iPad Air 4? The iPad Air 4 has the same height and width as the 2018 iPad Pro. The only things I can think would be different are:

- Air 4 is slightly thicker.
- Camera might be slightly different size?
- Magnets might be slightly

  different

Has anyone tried this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a keyboard folio case for my Air, which i previously used with the iPad Pro 2018. Regarding the iPad thickness i cannot see a negative effect, the additional thickness is rather small here. Also regarding your other points i don't see anything negative here.